# Cannot resolve symbol 'NanoHTTPD'

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, nanohttpd

I am trying to build NanoHTTPD into my project. I didn't find a solution in the other "Cannot resolve symbol" question on StackOverflow so I am trying this here I am sorry. This is a pretty fresh project.
I added the dependency of httpd in the pom.xml like this:

[image]

But it keeps telling me "Cannot resolve symbol 'NanoHTTPD'" if i hover over "extends NanoHTTPD" in my main class:

[image]

I don't know how to solve it and this project is very important for me...
I usually worked with gradle in Kotlin before and it worked fine but now I need to use Maven and I have never worked with it before.

Thanks already!!

Comment: `<scope>runtime</scope>` any particular reason for that?

Comment: It was standard written into the pom.xml. But no I don't really know what it does

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774)

Comment: Well, I removed it and it worked. Thank you very very much! You saved my day!

Comment: @GeroldBroser Ohh I didn't know. Thank you for showing me!